# How do I get this type of obj [{…}, {…}] and not this [] array?

Tags: arrays, angular, object

My goal is to display events I get from firestore using ng-fullcalendar.
But the problem is, it doesn't show up in the calendar.

If used mock data it works, but on data I got from firestore doesn't

So here's the working calendar with mock data

The function

```
  public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    const dateObj = new Date();
    const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
    let data: any = [{
        title: 'namee',
        start: '2018-09-19'
    },
    {
      title: 'STI night',
      start: '2018-09-18'
    }
  ];
    console.log(data);
    return of(data);
}
```

What displays in the console.log

[image]

And how I init the calendar with the event

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvents().subscribe(eventData => {
      console.log('Obs', eventData);
      this.calendarOptions = {
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
          events: eventData
      };    
    });

  }
```

[image: result]

The log on observable

[image]

But when I do this, the function that gets data from firestore

```
  getEventsCollection(): Observable<any>{
    this.eventService.getEventsCollection().subscribe(eventCollection => {
      eventCollection.forEach(event => {
        this.fullCalendarEvent = {
          title: event.event_name,
          start: event.event_date
        }        
        this.eventsArray.push(this.fullCalendarEvent);
      })

    });
     console.log( this.eventsArray  ); 
     return of(this.eventsArray);
  }
```

Which logs this

[image]

When I replace the function

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEventsCollection().subscribe(eventData => {
      console.log('Obs', eventData);
      this.calendarOptions = {
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
          events: eventData
      };    
    });

  }
```

[image]

But it doesn't show up in the calendar

[image]

Maaaan, my head hurts. Any tips on how to display them would be greatly apreciated!

**UPDATE**

Now I see the difference,

the mock data is this [{…}, {…}] (a what might be an object)

while mine is [] an array

Anyone knows how I can do so?

Comment: The data seems to be similar. It might be due to the async nature of the observable. Can you try wrapping the mock data in a setTimeout? So that the response is delayed?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.getEventsCollection().subscribe(eventData => {
      console.log('Obs', eventData);
      setTimeout(this.options(eventData), 9000);

    });

  } 

  options(eventData){
    this.calendarOptions = {
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
      },
        events: eventData
    };    
  }

Comment: Sad, t still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

It was the lifecycle hook all along!

When I put the init calendar in counstructor, voila,it worked!